# Ошибка алгоритма

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>

int ee = 7;
void qwerec( const void* buf  )
{   
    buf = (char * )& ee;
}
int Rec()
{
    int qr = 0;
    qwerec( (char * )&qr );
    return qr;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int qq = 5;
qq = Rec();
std::cout << qq;
    system ( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

Умные люди, подскажите почему выводит 0, а не 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй написать так:

```
void qwerec( const void* buf  )
{   
    *((int*) buf) = ee;
}
```

Comment: нет :)
вопрос в том, почему код ( тот что написан ) - выводит 0
как сделать иначе то я знаю :)
нет идей? просто либо я пересидел и уже голова не видит очевидных вещей, либо тут что то не так...

Comment: Все просто. Подумай о том, как в функцию передаются параметры в С/С++. Внутри функции создается копия передаваемого параметра, и когда ей присваивается какое-то значение, оно не передается наружу. Для того, чтобы изменить переменную вне функции, ей надо передать указатель и при присвоении разыменовать его, т.е. обратиться к той области памяти, на которую он указывает. Это делается с помощью оператора *(pointer).

Comment: мда..что то я тупанул - взял адрес, передал как параметр, изменил его и ждал что, что то произойдет)
спасибо :)